# Querying nodes using array property - neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, memgraphdb, opencypher

I have a property on the node which is stored as array of strings. But when I use this field to find the node, it's not returning any results. What am I doing wrong?

Below is the node:

```
MATCH (n:Product)
WHERE
n.id_product = 8
RETURN
n.keyterms
```

Result

```
["financial tool", "personal finance"]
```

I am trying to find the same node as above using the keyterms field:

```
MATCH (n:Product)
WHERE
["financial tool"] in n.keyterms
RETURN
n.keyterms

no records
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to put `"financial tool"`, in an array, simply try this:

```
MATCH (n:Product)
WHERE "financial tool" in n.keyterms
RETURN n.keyterms
```

To search for, multiple values, you can do the following:

```
MATCH (n:Product)
WHERE ANY (key IN n.keyterms WHERE key IN ['financial tool', 'personal finance'] )
RETURN n.keyterms
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. How about searching for multiple values? "financial tool" or "personal finance". Any option to do that in a single where clause?